# How to insert * symbol in mysql using php

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one field which contain data like `4563******3245`. when i execute my sql query it is inserted successfully. but in mysql database it is showing only `4563`

my sql query is:

```
insert into mytable ('myfield') values ('4563******3245');
```

Can any one tell me where is the problem.

thank you.

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: @ Daniel thank you. my column type was int. so now i changed to varchar. its now working.

Comment: @snehal then plz don't forget to rephrase/close and answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into mytable ('myfield') values ('4563******3245');
```

it is working fine

make sure your column type should be varchar

Answer (score 0):

You can't store text in a column of a number data type. You have to change your data type to `char(14)`.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY myfield CHAR(14);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your running that particular query, and only `4563` is being inserted, it would suggest your column type for "myfield" is set as some variant or length of "int" rather than char(22) (CCN's are not always 16 digits, some can be 20 or 22).

you should probably switch the column type to make sure the data inserts correctly to something like

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY myfield char(22);
```